# Understanding-pointer to a structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I want to understand how the pointer to the structure is passed to the function argument and implemented. How is `avrg_stpc[idx_u16].sum_f32` array is working?

```
typedef struct
{
    const float * input_f32p;
    float avg_f32;
    float sum_f32;
    float factor_f32;
    unsigned int rs_u16;
} avgminmax_avg_t;


void avgminmax_AvgCalculate_vd(
  avgminmax_avg_t * const avrg_stpc, 
  const unsigned int numOfEntrys_u16c)
{
    unsigned int idx_u16 = 0u;
    do
    {
        avrg_stpc[idx_u16].sum_f32 += (*avrg_stpc[idx_u16].input_f32p
                                 - avrg_stpc[idx_u16].avg_f32);
        avrg_stpc[idx_u16].avg_f32 = (avrg_stpc[idx_u16].sum_f32 *
                                      avrg_stpc[idx_u16].factor_f32);
        idx_u16++;
    }while(idx_u16 < numOfEntrys_u16c);
}
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, the `avg_f32` could be an *average*  (going by the `avg` prefix). Your multiplication doesn't calculate an average.

Comment: Look at the generated code sometime, at least in my case pointers went from an inpenetrable mystery to complete understanding over the course of a single afternoon by stepping through the code at the assembly level and looking at the changes in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few points that could help you understand arrays and pointers and their relationship:

- A pointer really only points to one "object", but that object might be the first in an array.
- Arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element.
- And array indexing is equivalent to pointers arithmetic (for any pointer or array `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is exactly equal to `*(a + i)`).

---

As for your specific example code, perhaps it would be easier if you thought of it similar to this:

```
avgminmax_avg_t *temp_ptr = &avrg_stpc[idx_u16];
temp_ptr->sum_f32 += ...;
temp_ptr->avg_f32 = ...;
```

Or perhaps like:

```
avgminmax_avg_t temp_object = avrg_stpc[idx_u16];
temp_object.sum_f32 += ...;
temp_object.avg_f32 = ...;
avrg_stpc[idx_u16] = temp_obj;
```

Both the snippets above will lead to the same result as your existing code, but requires an extra temporary variable, and in the latter snippet copying of the structure twice.

Comment: I'm sure you're very well versed in pointer arithmetic, but for the OP's sake, the 3rd point might need some further explanation. Pointer arithmetic happens in increments of the size of the thing that's pointed to, so if you have a pointer `a` of type `avgminmax_avg_t *`, the difference between the addresses that `a` and `a + 1` point to is `sizeof(avgminmax_avg_t)`.

Comment: Yes, I understand both the snippets and i was expecting "->" to access structure menbers but still don't get the point avrg_stpc[0].sum_f32, avrg_stpc[1].sum_f32 etc.

Comment: @litunbls So the question is really why you need to use the `.` member access operator instead of `->`? Then that's because the array indexing with `[]` already dereferences the pointer, `avrg_stpc[idx_u16]` isn't a pointer to a structure, it's a structure *object* that needs `.` for its members.

Comment: in my opinion the function is taking array of pointers to the structure. it should be like this with "[ ]"...."void avgminmax_AvgCalculate_vd(avgminmax_avg_t * const avrg_stpc[ ], 
  const unsigned int numOfEntrys_u16c)"

Comment: @litunbls If you have read any decent C beginners book, it should have told you that for argument declarations then declaring an array is the exact same as declaring a pointer. For an argument, `avgminmax_avg_t avrg_stpc[]` is exactly the same as `avgminmax_avg_t *avrg_stpc`. And `avgminmax_avg_t *avrg_stpc[]` makes `avrg_stpc` an array of *pointers*, its real type is `avgminmax_avg_t **avrg_stpc`. The types `avgminmax_avg_t *avrg_stpc[]` and `avgminmax_avg_t *avrg_stpc` are very different.

Answer (score 0):

`avrg_stpc` is regarded as an array (possibly, allocated on heap via `.*alloc`); since its bounds can't be known, hence the second argument to the function. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access